# Getting the density of states for photons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, photons, dimensional-analysis, density-of-states

I know that the density of states $g(\epsilon)d\epsilon$ is the number of states in the energy range $[\epsilon, \epsilon + d\epsilon]$.

I considered a system of non-interacting free photons in 3 dimensions.

**To calculate the density of states we just need:**

**1) The energy of our system.** In this case we are dealing with the energy of photons, so:

$$\epsilon = \hbar \omega $$

**2) The number of states with energy** $\le \epsilon$ (let's call it $N(\epsilon))$. As 3 dimensions are considered, the number of states is enclosed in a sphere:

$$N(\epsilon) = \frac{4}{3} \pi R^3$$

**Now I need to have the radius R in function of the energy so as to be able to compute the density of states:**

$$g(\epsilon) = \frac{dN}{d\epsilon}$$

As I considered a free photon, its momentum is:

$$p = \hbar k$$

$$p = \frac{h}{L} (n_x + n_y + n_z)$$

Then, the energy can be rewritten as:

$$\epsilon (n_x, n_y, n_z) = \frac{p \omega}{k} = \frac{hc}{L}(n_x + n_y + n_z)$$

This expression should be correct (I checked dimensions), **but it is not function of the radius.**

But I suspect that $(n_x + n_y + n_z)$ has something to do with a geometric figure, which encloses the number of states...

Now I work out another example, completely independent of the one above.

**COMPARISON WITH ANOTHER CASE TO SEE WHAT IS GOING ON**

Actually I tested if $(n_x + n_y + n_z)$ had something to do with the radius of a sphere (I assumed 3D) using the free particle's case (without relativistic effects):

$$\epsilon = \frac{p^2}{2m}$$

For the energy, I got:

$$\epsilon (n_x, n_y, n_z) = \frac{h^2}{2mL^2}(n_x^2 + n_y^2 + n_z^2)$$

At this point, I had the following thought:

$$(n_x^2 + n_y^2 + n_z^2) = R^2$$

And I gave it a shot... and ended up getting the correct density of states for the free particle (I also ignored spin as it is just about multiplying the final answer by a number).

**So I would say that** $(n_x + n_y + n_z)$ **has something to do with the radius.**

**To sum up, I have the following troubles**:

1') How can I get the radius from this equation $\epsilon (n_x, n_y, n_z) = \frac{p \omega}{k} = \frac{hc}{L}(n_x + n_y + n_z)$? Technically I cannot do 
$(n_x + n_y + n_z) = R$. Actually, I tried it but did not get it (at the end of my post I have written the density of states I should get).

2') In the $\epsilon = \frac{p^2}{2m}$ case I got:

$$\epsilon (n_x, n_y, n_z) = \frac{h^2}{2mL^2}(n_x^2 + n_y^2 + n_z^2) = \frac{h^2 R^2}{2mL^2}$$

But this expression does not have dimensions of energy! I mean, if I regard $(n_x, n_y, n_z)$  as axis of my phase space I have no problems with dimensions but once I regard $(n_x^2 + n_y^2 + n_z^2)= R^2$ dimensions do not match in the equation for the above energy... but I get the right result! **what is going on here?**

3) Why the dimension of the density of states is time in photons and in the free particle case (assuming nonrelativistic quantum mechanics) is $\frac{T^2}{ML^2}$?

I know that the density of states of free photons (assuming Plank's energy; see Griffiths, page 244;  EQ 5.112; second edition):

$$g(\omega) = \frac{V \omega^2}{\pi c^3}$$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: First of all, momentum is a vector even in the photon case. That said $p = |\overrightarrow p| = \sqrt{n_x^2 + n_y^2 + n_z^2}/L$.

Comment: @rnels12 I think it should be $p = |\overrightarrow p| = h\sqrt{n_x^2 + n_y^2 + n_z^2}/L$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that you ignore $\boldsymbol{k}$ being a **vector**. In fact

$$\boldsymbol{p}=\hbar \boldsymbol{k}=\frac{h}{L}\boldsymbol{n}$$

where $\boldsymbol{n}=\left(n_{x},n_{y},n_{z}\right)$. This gives you

$$R=\left|\boldsymbol{n}\right|=\frac{L}{h}\left|\boldsymbol{p}\right|=\frac{L}{hc}\varepsilon=\frac{L}{2\pi c}\omega$$

so (the factor of $2$ accounts for the two polarizations of the photon)

$$N\left(\omega\right)=2\cdot\frac{4}{3}\pi R^{3}=\frac{8\pi L^{3}}{3 \left(2\pi\right)^{3} c^3}\omega^{3}=\frac{V}{3 \pi^{2} c^3}\omega^{3}$$

$$g\left(\omega\right)=\frac{\partial N\left(\omega\right)}{\partial\omega}=\frac{V}{\pi^{2} c^3}\omega^{2}$$

Comment: thank you, your answer is helpful! Why $R=\left|\boldsymbol{n}\right|$ is the radius?

Comment: Because $\boldsymbol{n}=\left(n_{x},n_{y},n_{z}\right)$ satisfies $\left|\boldsymbol{n}\right|\leq \frac{L}{2\pi c}\omega\equiv R$, and $\boldsymbol{n}$ is like $\boldsymbol{r}=\left(x,y,z\right)$.

Comment: there is also a hyperphysics-page that you might find useful: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/phodens.html