# Density of states of bosons in function of momentum with energy $\epsilon = cp$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, density-of-states

I am working out an average number **N** of bosons of spin $S = 0$ connected to a two-dimensional domain with surface **A**. The gas is ultrarelativistic with a single particle energy $\epsilon = cp$.

The first thing that came to my mind was: this problem takes relativity into account; we are dealing with photons! Note that this energy is the Plank's one:

$$\epsilon = cp = c \hbar k = \hbar \omega$$

So I had a clear idea in mind; it was just about doing:

$$N \approx \int_0^{\infty} \frac{g(\omega)d\omega}{e^{\beta(\epsilon - \mu)} - 1}$$

**But, surprisingly,  I was suggested to integrate over momentum instead:**

$$N \approx \frac{2 \pi A}{h^2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{p dp}{e^{\beta(pc - \mu)} - 1}$$

Then, **the suggested** $g(p)$ is:

$$g(p) = \frac{2 \pi Ap}{h^2}$$

The first thing I did was to use dimensional analysis on the given density of states: $\frac{T }{ML}$. *A priori* made sense, because if the density of states in function of the energy $g(\epsilon)$ has dimensions of $[\epsilon]^{-1}$ , why not $g(p)$ having dimensions of $[p]^{-1}$?

So let's assume the latest integral is OK. What I did to try to get it was calculating the density of states $g(\epsilon)$ with the idea of make it at the end function of p. So I got:

$$g(\epsilon) = \frac{32 \pi^3 L^2 \epsilon}{h^2 \lambda^2 \omega^2}$$

Which has dimensions of $[\epsilon]^{-1}$. As $p =\frac{h}{L}$ (note that here $L = \lambda$):

**DETAILS ON THE CALCULATION.**

**1) Energy:**

$$\epsilon = cp = c \hbar k = \hbar \omega = \frac{p \lambda \omega}{2 \pi} = \frac{h \lambda \omega}{2 L \pi}\sqrt{n_x^2 + n_y^2}$$

Where:

$$\boldsymbol{n}=\left(n_{x},n_{y} \right)$$

$$R=\left|\boldsymbol{n}\right|= \frac{2 L \pi \epsilon}{h \lambda \omega}$$

R turns out to be dimensionless, which is a good sign.

**2) The number of states** $N(\epsilon)$

$$N(\epsilon) = 4\pi R^2 = \frac{16 \pi^3 L^2 \epsilon^2}{h^2 \lambda^2 \omega^2}$$

Now:

$$g(\epsilon) = \frac{dN}{d\epsilon}$$

$$g(\epsilon) = \frac{32 \pi^3 L^2 \epsilon}{h^2 \lambda^2 \omega^2}$$

$g(\epsilon)$ turns out to have dimensions of $[\epsilon]^{-1}$, which is a good sign.

Now we want to get $g(p)$ out of $g(\epsilon)$ so we use the energy:

$$\epsilon = cp$$

So the $g(p)$ I got is:

$$g(p) = \frac{32 \pi^3 L^2 cp}{h^2 \lambda^2 \omega^2}$$

**END ON DETAILS ON CALCULATION.**

As you can see they do not match.

**Note that the dimensions for my** $g(p)$ **are** $[\epsilon]^{-1}$ **in contrast with the suggested** $g(p)$**, which has dimensions of** $[p]^{-1}$. **Are both expressions OK? I would say no, because dimensions do not depend on the approach used; they cannot change, as both approaches work on momentum space.**

**Then, how can I get the density of states in function of momentum?**

Comment: Where did you get your function $g(\epsilon)$ from?

Comment: @BySymmetry $\epsilon = \hbar \omega$, $N(\epsilon) = 4\pi R^2$ and $g(\epsilon) = \frac{dN}{d\epsilon}$ Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: What is $R$ here?

Comment: The radius. You may be interested in seeing this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/447054/getting-the-density-of-states-for-photons

Comment: The radius of what exactly? (I did look at the previous question) What is $\lambda$?

Comment: @BySymmetry In this problem,$R$ is the radius of the circle (we are working in 2D) which encloses the number of states $N(\epsilon)$

Comment: You are confusing terms here. Why is $p=\frac{h}{L}$ a constant? Why don't you write the density of states $g(\varepsilon)$ with $\varepsilon$ instead of $\lambda$ and $\omega$? I would suggest you to show your entire calculation, step by step, so we can find where exactly you have a problem.

Comment: @eranreches Do you think the best approach here would be firstly get $g(\varepsilon)$ and from that expression get $g(p)$? I will update my question.

Comment: I don't think there is a "best" approach here. Just calculate first the density of states you find the easiest, and then change variables if needed. You can also calculate $g(p)$ directly. But, no matter what way you choose to follow, please elaborate your steps.

Comment: @eranreches I fixed some mistakes. The thing is getting more interesting...

Comment: First of all, you are mixing too many parameters. You need to use $\varepsilon$ **or** $p$ **or** $k$ **or** $\lambda$ **or** $\omega$ - not all of them at the same time. Then, imposing the boundary condition you can quantize $k$ or any other variable. This is then used to calculate the volume $\pi R^{2}$ in the phase space of this variable!

Comment: @eranreches I did $\epsilon = cp = c \hbar k = \hbar \omega = \frac{p \lambda \omega}{2 \pi} = \frac{h \lambda \omega}{2 L \pi}\sqrt{n_x^2 + n_y^2}$ In order to get $g(\epsilon)$. Please explain the way I can approach this generally. I have just seen how to work with $\varepsilon$...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87079/discussion-between-eranreches-and-jd-pm).

Comment: Hint: you can use $g(\epsilon)d\epsilon = g(p)dp$.

Comment: @Dani Thank you for your help, my doubt has been solved.